# Storing 1000s of thumbnails

Tags: image, storage

I have about 1 million thumbnails that I have on my harddisk and that is really increasing the latency on the disk.

Now how can i store those thumbnails on the harddrive to that improve the performance and also fast fetching.

How do organisations like facebook, google images, etc store their images?

I have 10TB storage so that is not a problem. The problem is with the number of images.

Comment: Are all your thumbs in one directory (or in a small number of directories)?

Comment: If you're on windows: Are the files split into folders of 400-8000 files each, with 400-8000 parent folders each? NTFS [has a setting that generates 8.3-style filenames](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007), which can really slow things down. You can turn it off, it's on by default. Also, IIS and ASP.NET need some tweaking to handle that file count properly. Personally, I suggest Amazon S3 and CloudFront.

Answer (score 2):

Is this for a web application? If so, the thumbnails (and other stuff) might benefit from actually moving off your hard drive and onto a content delivery network. Large sites (as well as those trying to speed up content delivery) typically use content delivery networks (CDNs) to serve data that's mirrored all over the globe to ensure fast access regardless of where the request comes from.

I've used [Rackspace CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/) and would recommend it, but this obviously isn't useful if you're looking to serve these images directly from the hard drive in question.

Answer (score 0):

A RAID 0 would be an interesting idea... Though I doubt the usefulness of a million *thumbnails*.

Google & co store their information on multiple servers, which are most of the time backed-up by RAID and other fast-access/safekeeping methods. So that'd be your best bet :)

Comment: @user658911 Next step are SSDs but as Matt said, you're better off with a Cloud Storage/CDN if you want to distribute these files on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Bildero image server - it allows to store and serve large amount of images. It has also some usefull features like dynamic resizing, custom watermarks, dynamic crop, zoom, spin, and many more - [Bildero](http://www.bildero.com)